# how to get value from database and show in dropdown list

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, database

I already try many ways but the value didn't show in dropdown list
 Here, this is my code. can you suggest me anything that i was wrong

```
<?php  
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM project"); 

    if( mysqli_num_rows( $result )==0){
    echo "<tr><td>No Rows Returned</td></tr>";
  }else{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );
      $pos = 0;
      echo "<select name=Pname >"; 
        while($pos <= count ($row)){ 
      echo "<option value="$row["project_no"]">"$row["project_name"]"</option>";
           $pos++;
          }
echo "</select>";?>
```

And i write as .php file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't use double quotes everywhere and concatenate. Also why not `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result )){`? You should look at your error logs there should be things being reported with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$output = '';
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    // echo error;
} else {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $project_no = $row['project_no'];
        $project_name = $row['project_name'];

        $output .= '<option value="' . $project_no . '">' . $project_name . '</option>";
    }
}
```

Then inside of your HTML, print your `$output` variable inside of your `<select>` element:

```
<select>
<?php
    print("$output");
?>
</select>
```

It should print all options for every row that you have requested from the database.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You should add an explanation as well to why the OPs code failed.

Comment: @chris85 good idea! Will do :) pretty new to this, so still getting used to posting.

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic Thanks for your help. Your code can work well but it didnt print all row in database out. And finally, i can figure it out . Thank you very much

Comment: All rows that you have requested, haha ;) thanks for selecting it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM project");

if( mysqli_num_rows( $result )==0){
    echo "<tr><td>No Rows Returned</td></tr>";
}else{
    echo "<select name=Pname >";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<option value="$row["project_no"]">"$row["project_name"]"</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: `mysql_` doesnt work with `mysqli` answers should have a write up of why the OP should try the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result code that i can run it.  I put this code in a form code of html

`$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM project"); ?>
        <?php
        $output = '';
         if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
             // echo error;
         } else {
              echo "  <select name = Pname>";
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                   $project_no = $row['project_no'];
                   $project_name = $row['project_name'];
                   $output = "<option value=" . $project_no . "> ". $project_name ." </option>";
                   print("$output"); 
              }
              echo " </select>";
         }
        ?>`

Thank you every one for helping me ^^